# Accessing WordPress installation in its own directory at domain root

Tags: directory, domain-mapping

I am using this tutorial [Giving WordPress Its Own Directory](http://codex.wordpress.org/Giving_WordPress_Its_Own_Directory#Using_a_pre-existing_subdirectory_install) to launch a WordPress (installed in a sub folder called `wordpress`) by using example.com instead of example.com/wordpress.

It says to copy `index.php` to your root folder and change the relative path to `wp-blog-header.php` accordingly. However, my folder structure is a little complex:

[image: Folder Structure]

To access site root I go to example.com. But to access WordPress I have to go to example.com/wordpress (if anyone wondering why I am using Bitnami WordPress stack AMI and thus everything came pre-configured)

According to tutorial I should copy `index.php` to site root from WordPress root and change relative location of `wp-blog-header.php` accordingly.
When index.php was in same directory the function was `require('./wp-blog-header.php')` . Now this location is to be changed

I have tried all three options I could think of:

1. `../apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php`
2. `./wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php`
3. `wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php`

But visiting the domain root gives a server error. Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I think you need to use:

```
define("ROOT", realpath(dir(__file__)) . "/");
require(ROOT . "apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php");
```

Got this from the [PHP.Net](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) site however haven't used the code (Or use this type of code often) so can't guarantee it will work.

Cheers,
Joe

Answer (score 1):

Here is the answer http://wiki.bitnami.org/Components/Apache#How_to_change_the_URL.3f
it was because of bitnami and not a fault of wordpress

Answer (score 1):

I have used a setup *similar* to this on a different server. You need to code the **full path** to the WordPress installation into the require function. On a regular server this would start with `/home/username/`.

If you don't know the full path, you can use the [`dirname()`](http://php.net/dirname) function:

```
require( dirname( dirname( __FILE__ ) ) . '/apps/wordpress/htdocs/wp-blog-header.php');
```

The first call to `dirname( __FILE__ )` returns the path to the htdocs (site root) folder. The second exits that folder to the Bitnami root.